# wavemaker and postgresql 9.3

Tags: json, postgresql-9.3, wavemaker

I won't use the new function from **postgresql 9.3** (JSON->"key") in SQL query. but it doesn't work. I look in the **Wavemaker 6.7** folder and see jar lib **"postgresql-9.0-801. jdbc4. jar"** its older version without JSON function. What can I do? I'm trying to paste new driver, but it's don't help me.`

```
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2014-04-04 19:10:39,310 ERROR [org.hibernate.hql.PARSER] - <line 1:11: unexpected token: >> (session E10C8E6D4B9DE5EAFF98F0F5004048D2, thread 30 invoke dataService.runQuery)
2014-04-04 19:10:39,313 ERROR [com.wavemaker.runtime.server.JSONRPCController] - <unexpected token: > near line 1, column 11 [select js->'b' from com.bddb.data.Test _a where _a.id=:id
]> (session E10C8E6D4B9DE5EAFF98F0F5004048D2, thread 30)
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: > near line 1, column 11 [select js->'b' from com.bddb.data.Test _a where _a.id=:id
]
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:31)
at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:24)
```

type column **js** in hibernate - **serializable**, in postgres - **json**

how can I get value from json in query?

Comment: "It doesn't work". What, *exactly* does not work, and how? What happens? What is the *exact text* of any error message?

Comment: i can't understand change lib postgres9.0 or not. And in HQL query i can't get value from JSON string in row

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say there. Look, is there an error message when you try to run your query? **What is the error message**? (Edit your question. Paste the error message. Save the edit. Comment here when done.)